# Use String in SoundPool play

Tags: android, soundpool

I'm using SoundPool for my android app. I load about 75 one- to three-second sounds into the pool in my main activity and then reference them from other activities using the Sound method which looks like this:

```
    public void Sound(int s){
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    float volume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    MainActivity.spool.play(s, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
};
```

s is the integer I define in the MainActivity class, for example:

```
static int sound_e;
```

and then pass into the Sound method like this:

```
Sound(sound_e);
```

I would like to be able to define a string like this:

```
String letter_sound = "MainActivity.sound_" + currentLetter; 
//Example value of this string would be MainActivity.sound_a
```

And then pass that string into Sound as an integer. This is to avoid 26 if statements, which I did for the numbers like this:

```
if (randomNum == 1) {Log.v(TAG,  "Sound playing for: " + randomNum); Sound(MainActivity.sound_1);}
        else if (randomNum == 2) {Log.v(TAG,  "Sound playing for: " + randomNum); Sound(MainActivity.sound_2);}
        else if (randomNum == 3) {Log.v(TAG,  "Sound playing for: " + randomNum); Sound(MainActivity.sound_3);}
        else if (randomNum == 4) {Log.v(TAG,  "Sound playing for: " + randomNum); Sound(MainActivity.sound_4);}
        else if (randomNum == 5) {Log.v(TAG,  "Sound playing for: " + randomNum); Sound(MainActivity.sound_5);}
        else if (randomNum == 6) {Log.v(TAG,  "Sound playing for: " + randomNum); Sound(MainActivity.sound_6);}
        else if (randomNum == 7) {Log.v(TAG,  "Sound playing for: " + randomNum); Sound(MainActivity.sound_7);}
        else if (randomNum == 8) {Log.v(TAG,  "Sound playing for: " + randomNum); Sound(MainActivity.sound_8);}
        else if (randomNum == 9) {Log.v(TAG,  "Sound playing for: " + randomNum); Sound(MainActivity.sound_9);}
        else if (randomNum == 10) {Log.v(TAG,  "Sound playing for: " + randomNum); Sound(MainActivity.sound_10);}
        else Log.v(TAG, "None of the ifs are true. randomNum: " + randomNum);
```

I didn't see in the android documentation any way to pass string values into the SoundPool play, just integers. Thanks for helping me figure out what I'm missing!

Comment: To do exactly what you want I think you need reflection, but I also think there are other ways to do it (regular method call?). All I can say for now is that you can swap those else-if's for a switch-case statement, and there's no need to repeat that `Log.v` statement

Comment: The else-ifs are in switch statements for different voice choices. I wasn't sure about nesting the switch statements.

Comment: You could simply put it in a separate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using SoundPool for my android app. I load about 75 one- to three-second sounds into the pool in my main activity and then reference them from other activities using the Sound method...

Firstly...DO NOT DO THIS. The Android `Activity` class is not just a normal Java class and the proper (and safe) Android programming approach is that an `Activity` should be self-contained. Other `Activities` or app components should not have access to `public` methods or data fields.

If you wan't to provide a common class to be used by multiple app components then simply create a 'helper' POJO class. If it needs to use a `Context` (as `SoundPool` does for example), you can simply pass the `Activity` context into methods as `this`. Be careful about holding a reference to the `Activity` `Context` however as it can cause memory leaks.

Secondly to give an easy answer to your problem...

The `load(...)` methods of `SoundPool` return a `soundID` which is what you use to call the `play(...)` method. If all you want to do is play a random sound then simply create an array of some sort and use the random number to get the `soundID` from the array by index. Simple - just one line of code to access the relevant `soundID`.

Comment: Great, great ,GREAT answer! Thank you! Very helpful information about self-containing activities to avoid memory leaks as well. Thanks!

Comment: I added a config class and I am now able to call all my sounds with one line like this: `Config.Sound(Config.alphabetSoundsArray_voice1[currentIndex], Game2Show.this);` you are awesome!!

Comment: Glad to be of help. :)